# Given a number, foreach 3rd digit do something

Tags: php, string, foreach, sum

Lets say i have a number like below:

```
$number = "20160513123"
```

So what i want to do is,
Starting from 2, for each third digit i want to multiply and find the sum.
So basically i want to get the number 2,6,1,2 from the string
and multiply each number by 3 and then calculate the sum of all the multiplication. 
Like so:

```
2 * 3, 
6 * 3,
1 * 3,
2 * 3,
```

Then i want to get the sum of all of the above. How is that possible using PHP?

Comment: How far did you get when you tried to write this script yourself? What went wrong? What didn't work? In what way did it "not work," how did it fail?

Comment: You haven't included your latest/best attempt to self-solve.

Comment: show your code  ... this is not a free coding service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `range` function to step through your characters:

```
$number = "20160513123";

$sum = 0;
foreach (range(0, strlen($number), 3) as $i) {
    $sum += 3*$number[$i];
}

echo $sum;
```

Output:

> 33

If you like *functional programming*, then this may be according to your liking:

```
$sum = 3 * array_sum(array_map(
           function($i) use ($number) { return $number[$i]; },
           range(0, strlen($number), 3)
       ));
```

Or, with the use of `str_split`, you can get chunks of 3 characters:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map(
           function($s) { return 3*$s[0]; },
           str_split($number, 3)
       ));
```

NB: Note that you can either multiply each number with 3 separately, or just the sum.

#### Compact solution

One final alternative. It uses `array_chunk` and `array_column` to filter out the desired digits (it seems PHP has functions for most anything):

```
$sum = 3 * array_sum(array_column(array_chunk(str_split($number), 3), 0));
```

Take your pick ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### CasimiretHippolyte's tiny, tiny one-liner

(you're not going to find a smaller one-liner for this question):

```
echo array_sum(preg_split('/.\K..?/',$number))*3;
```

This explodes `$number` after this first character by every 2 (or 1) character to follow, adds up the remaining numbers and multiplies them.  Just clever awesome!

---

CasimiretHippolyte's previous solution:

```
if(preg_match_all('/..\K./',"00$number",$matches)){
    echo array_sum($matches[0])*3;
}
```

Though it required left-padding the string, this method used shorter/simpler regex and produced a leaner `$matches` array, compared to my solution below:

---

mickmackusa's solution:

```
if(preg_match_all("/(\d)(?:\d\d|\d$|$)/",$number,$matches)){
    echo array_sum($matches[1])*3;
}
```

My regex matches all single digits that are followed by either: 2 digits,
1 digit & end of line, or end of line.  This method steps past the non-capture group digits when it can, so only 1st, 4th, 7th, etc. are captured.

All codes above output:

> ```
> 33
> ```

Comment: It's easier to pad the subject string on the left with two characters: https://eval.in/761265

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I've never used/seen \K before.  I'm lovin that.  Definitely gonna be using that one in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using [***str_split***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function(to get an array of digits):

```
$number = "20160513123";
$total_sum = 0;
foreach (str_split($number) as $k => $n) {
    if ($k % 3 == 0) $total_sum += $n * 3;  // considering each third digit
}

print_r($total_sum);   // 33
```